# Infinite Loop on OpenGL

Tags: c, opengl, glut

I decided that whenever the user tries to resize the screen the screen must go back to preset sizes, so it makes my life easier on graph nodes drawing. On MAC, my application is working properly but on Linux it is happening an infinte loop on the resize function, and I don't know why. After some loop calls I got a Segmentation fault (core dumped)

here's my opengl configuration(main funciton)

```
glutInit(&argc, argv);
glutInitDisplayMode ( GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);
glutInitWindowSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
glutCreateWindow(APP_NAME);
glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);         // black background
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);              // setup viewing projection
glLoadIdentity();                           // start with identity matrix
glOrtho(0.0, 50.0, 0.0, 50.0, 0.0, 0.1);   // setup a 50x50 viewing world
glutDisplayFunc(display);
glutReshapeFunc(resize);
glutMainLoop();
```

and here's my display and resize functions implementations

```
void display() {
      Matrix* distanceMatrix = NULL;
      PalleteNodePosition* nodesPositions = NULL;
      distanceMatrix = fromFile(inputFileName);
      printf("Finish input parsing...\n");
      nodesPositions = calculateNodesPositions(distanceMatrix);
      printf("Finish calculating nodes position on screen...\n");
      glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
      drawNodes(nodesPositions, distanceMatrix->width);
      drawLink(10, 10, 18, 18);
      glFlush();
}

void resize(int w, int h){
      glutReshapeWindow(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
}
```

When I print the resize call, I got w equals to WINDOW_WIDTH and h equals to WINDOW_HEIGHT as expected, so why the app is resizing the screen everytime?

Answer (score 1):

Your `resize()` callback will be indirectly called by itself even if it
is in an asynchronous way.
You ask the windowing system to resize your window, then later
you receive the event that says that your window has been resized,
then your callback is triggered, which leads to a new resize
request...
If nobody stops this loop (apparently the windowing system
does not detect that the resize is not actually needed),
it is infinite.

May be should you consider comparing `w` and `h` to the expected
values, inside your `resize()` callback, and only invoke `glutReshapeWindow()` if it is actually needed?

You should also be aware that the inner size and the outer size
of the window are probably different (border, title-bar...).

Comment: yep. I tried getting the current window size with

glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH)
glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT)

but these values are different from my WINDOW_WIDTH and WINDOW_HEIGHT constants. So the loop persists

Comment: you mean do this comparing inside main function before registering the callback?

Comment: @JoãoLucasGouveia I tried to clarify the context in the answer.

Comment: got it. I tried your tips here and I have some good path to follow, it is working, I dont have the infinite loop anymore, but the window is not resinzing properly yet. Thanks a lot for the tips